# If $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix satisfying $(A - 2I)^3 = 0$ and $(A - 2I)^2 \neq 0$, what are the possible Jordan canonical forms for $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this problem is supposed to be easy, but I'm very confused on it.

I know that the assumption $(A - 2I)^3 = 0$ means that the matrix $A - 2I$ is nilpotent.

But to know the possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$, don't I need to know the eigenvalues of $A$? Is $\lambda = 2$ the only eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$(A-2I)^3=0$ implies minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ of $A$ divides $(x-2)^3$. Thus $$m_A(x) \in \Big\{(x-2),(x-2)^2,(x-2)^3\Big\}$$ But $(A-2I)^2 \neq 0$ implies $m_A(x) \neq (x-2)^2$ and $m_A(x) \neq (x-2)$ So $m_A(x) =(x-2)^3$. Thus the possible forms of JCF are corresponding to

- a  block of size $3$ with eigenvalue $2$

Comment: If the minimal polynomial were $x-2$, then we should have that $(A-2I)^2 = 0$. This means that we have to have a Jordan block of size three — is this correct?

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I edit my answer